# How to extract a point in LibGdx from Tiled map?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Tiled has a feature to insert a point in to an Object layer. But there doesn't seem to be a "PointMapObject" implementation in Libgdx on the [doc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapObject.html). currently i am being forced to use a PolylineMap Object with two vertices but all i want is only the x or y of the first vertex.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? How are you loading the Tiled file? Do you need a specific format in libgdx or can you use your own classes?

Comment: @jay I am loading the tiled file using libgdx's assetManager by setting its map loader like this <pre>assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class,new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));<code> i am not sure what u meant by ur last question but if u meant like writing my own tiledmap loader, i can try but i think it would be too much hussle.

Comment: Just not sure what you mean when you say you have to use two vertices instead of the first one?

Comment: @Jay tiled doesn't allow you to create a polyline with just one vertex. it must atleast have two vertices.

Comment: Ah I understand what your problem is now. I'm not familiar with gdx so not sure about a solution. Just had a look at the docs and it might be worth looking at `TextureMapObject` and `TiledMapTileMapObject`

Comment: Are you sure the points don't simply load in libGDX as RectangleMapObject instances with 0 width/height? They were added only recently in Tiled so I'm not surprised libGDX doesn't have a dedicated type for it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually points in LibGDX are treated as RectangleMapObject with height=0.0 and width=0.0.

Below debbuger output of object that is point on the tiled side:

[image]